# Rails replace simple ActiveRecord relation in case of big amount of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app controller looks pretty simple:

```
class ProductsController
  before_action :set_company

  def index
    @products = company.products.includes(:shipment)
  end

  private

  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end
end
```

But what I worry about is the `@product` inside Index action was properly declared? What if I'll have millions of products? is there more efficient solution?

Model relations below:

```
class Products < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :shipment
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :products
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a problem if you have million of records because your query is going to be too big, in this case you can add pagination in any flavor or use any other strategy that reduce the number of records queried each time.

To do pagination in Rails you can use https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari but this is not the only strategy available to do this.

Comment: Filtering comes to my mind. Something like `recent_products`.

Comment: Yes, filtering is another good option, all depends on the use case you're trying to solve